# Azure devops automate target vm deletion from deployment group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment

There is a method available for deleting a target machine from an azure deployment group using the API and its documentation can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Is there a similar functionality available as a powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a PowerShell module available for Azure DevOps. However, you can invoke the same Azure DevOps REST APIs through the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet.

Here is how:

```
$Username =""
$Password="<Personal-Access-Token>"

$Tokens = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password)))
$Authheader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + $Tokens }

# Targets - Delete REST API
$Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{deploymentGroupId}/targets/{targetId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method delete -Headers $Authheader
```

Comment: The problem could be the script would be executed in a release pipeline step and authorised using a service principal id and PAT token. Its certainly worth a try though, I will see if I can adapt the authorisation, thanks Bhargavi.

Comment: @Evan Sure, happy to help if you have further questions! Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it helpful. :)